# beforeSave function not working on JavaScript SDK 1.6.x

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm using Parse iOS SDK 1.8.5, and for CloudCode I'm using JavaScript SDK 1.6.4.

When I saved a new Parse object from iOS, and CloudCode is like this for testing.

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave( "Post", function(request, response) {
    response.success();
});
```

After that, the object is saved to the database, but all fields are null.

When I removed the beforeSave function from the CloudCode, all fields are saved properly.

I tested Javascript SDK from 1.5.0 to 1.6.4, all 1.6.x SDKs are same result.

Is there a information about that?

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem. Simply went further down to v1.4.2 and it restarted working again.

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32705381/4988014) thread please.