# Cloud code - Parse.Object initializer isn't working

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm probably missing something stupid, but my initializer function for a custom parse class isn't working in cloud code.  I have the following in my cloud code, and call the "createAStatisticTest" function from my client, which successfully creates and saves a new Statistics object, but doesn't update any of the data to 0.  All of the data is (undefined).  Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

```
var Statistics = Parse.Object.extend("Statistics",
    { //instance methods
        initialize: function(attrs, options)
        {
            this.newUsers = 0;
            this.newBillableUsers = 0;
            this.firstCut = 0;
            this.additionalCuts = 0;
            this.numCuts = 0;
            this.totalBillableUsers = 0;
        }
    },
    {} //class methods
);

//Create a single statistics object to show that the parameters inside of the intialize function aren't being set properlly
Parse.Cloud.define("createAStatisticTest", function(request, status)
{
    var statistics = new Statistics();
    statistics.save().then
    (
        function( statistics )
        {
            status.success("Saved the statistic object");
        },
        function( error )
        {
            status.error("There was an error saving the object: " + error.message);
        }
    )
});
```

I based my implementation off of the js guide's Monster object example found [here](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#objects)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem a few weeks ago, where everything returned `(undefined)` suddenly. I solved it by changing the JavaScript SDK version back to version 1.4.2 - so it seems Parse has a bug in their latest SDK version.

Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32705381/4988014) answer.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work for me, unfortunately. Oddly enough, my version was already set to 1.4.2 instead of latest, anyway. I tried setting it to both "latest" and to "1.6.6" (the latest listed on the downloads page), but neither worked.  I was hoping I had some really stupid syntax error, but apart from only having the one instance method and no class methods, I don't see any difference between what I'm doing and the example from the guide.