# Request.object has no data in afterSave hook

Tags: parse-platform

I'm trying to make use of the `afterSave` hook in Parse.

However even a simple print out of the ID from the object that was just saved does not show in logs, and `if` statements do not pass to allow other methods to be performed. The relevant code:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave(Parse.User, function(request) {
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  var user = request.object;
  console.log('After save for user ID: ', user.id);
  if (!user.existed() && user.get('isTrainer')) {
  // does not enter here
```

The log that prints out has no ID, just the string I typed. I also tried printing out the request object but the Parse logging system doesn't seem capable of printing out objects which is unfortunate. It also doesn't enter the `if` statement because using `get` also returns no information.

Anyone have an idea of why this might be?

For completeness here is the object so you can see its being saved correctly:

```
v31 after_save triggered for _User for user PlVMz2zCfC:
  Input: {"object":{"createdAt":"2015-12-24T21:01:01.678Z","email":"yui@bb.bb","firstName":"Pppp","isTrainer":true,"lastName":"Pop","objectId":"PlVMz2zCfC","phone":"(555) 555-5555","trainer":{"__type":"Relation","className":"Trainer"},"updatedAt":"2015-12-24T21:01:01.678Z","username":"yui@bb.bb"}}
  Result: Success
```

Comment: What about adding a fetch in there as well?

Comment: Adding a fetch results in the error `Result: TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'fetch'`.

Comment: What happens if you try *console.log('After save for user ID: ', request.object.id);*  ?

Comment: Maybe you're experiencing this bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33026491/request-object-id-not-returning-in-aftersave-in-cloud-code/33138792#33138792

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an afterSave trigger on the User class, you should use `request.user` instead of `request.object`

I find it helpful to output everything to the console during development to help with debugging.

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave(Parse.User, function(request) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var user = request.user;

    console.log("user = " + JSON.stringify(user));
    console.log("user.id = " + JSON.stringify(user.id));
    console.log("user.existed() = " + JSON.stringify(user.existed()));
    console.log("user.get("isTrainer") = " + JSON.stringify(user.get("isTrainer")));

    if (!user.existed() && user.get("isTrainer")) {
        ...
```

Comment: Unfortunately this has the same result: no ID is printed in the console log, and it does not enter the `if` statement.

Comment: Try using `console.log("request.user = " + JSON.stringify(request.user));` and let me know if anything shows up.

Comment: It does! `request.user = {"createdAt":"2015-12-25T02:34:19.005Z","email":"ff@bb.nn","firstName":"Gggg","isTrainer":true,"lastName":"Ffgg","phone":"(555) 555-5555","sessionToken":"xx","trainer":{"__type":"Relation","className":"Trainer"},"updatedAt":"2015-12-25T02:34:19.005Z","username":"ff@bb.nn","objectId":"yzQGLpBuC5"}`. So that's a great way to see an object output. Why do the `get`s and `.id` notational not work though?

Comment: See my updated answer and try to output each of the statements individually to help trace what's going on. As to why a `get` or `id` may not work can vary. Sometimes it could be due to ACLs or some of the special security precautions that Parse has built into the `User` class. Regardless, those shouldn't matter since you're using the master key

Comment: The result: `user = {"createdAt":"2015-12-25T02:49:24.109Z","email":"gg@hh.bbt","firstName":"Hhgg","isTrainer":true,"lastName":"Ffff","phone":"(555) 555-5555","sessionToken":"8uy3Ta6vh1FMQQWKYPgA8wTWe","trainer":{"__type":"Relation","className":"Trainer"},"updatedAt":"2015-12-25T02:49:24.109Z","username":"gg@hh.bbt","objectId":"QwX47B0TuC"}
user.id = "QwX47B0TuC"
user.existed() = true
user.get(isTrainer) =` 
Strangely `existed()` returns `true`, but this is a new user.

Comment: Has your question been answered? :)