# Parse cloud code new SDK include subclass not working

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I was using an old parse SDK version 1.5.0 and my function was returning with all the includes.
Now I tried to use the latest SDK and the function is returning the main object only (on the gate and location I get "pointers" only.).

Here is the code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("get_gates_for_user", function(request, response) {
    var userId = request.params.userId;


var gateToUserQuery = new Parse.Query("GateUserJoinTable");
gateToUserQuery.equalTo("user", {
            __type: "Pointer",
            className: "_User",
            objectId: userId
        });


gateToUserQuery.include("gate");
gateToUserQuery.include("location");

gateToUserQuery.find({
    success: function(results) {
        response.success(results);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        response.error(ERROR_CODE_GENERAL_ERROR);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Maybe related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33059768/parse-com-javascript-sdk-using-include-but-not-working

Comment: yes seems to be the same issue! Also I tried the code using JavaScript  ( on a browser page) and I can get all the sub-classes information.

Comment: Yes, the same than my post. I don't understand why. There's a way to to do it but it comes out as a dictionary, not like `List<ParseObject>`

Answer (score 0):

I started working with Parse recently so I'm not very familiar with the behavioiur of old SDK versions.

Since you're in Cloud Code, however, `.include()` doesn't warrant a significant performance gain over `.fetch()`, since the code runs on their infrastructure (it's the documented way of accessing related `Parse.Object`s, so they should be optimizing for that anyway), so the following should work:

```js
var _ = require('underscore');
var results;
gateToUserQuery.find().then(function (joins) {
  // add results to bigger-scoped variable
  // for access in the other function
  results = joins;

  // Promises are beautiful
  var fetchPromises = _.map(results, function (join) {
    return Parse.Promise.when([
      join.get('gate').fetch(),
      join.get('location').fetch()
    ]));
  });
  return Parse.Promise.when(fetchPromises);
}).then(function () {
  // related Pointers should be filled with data
  response.success(results);
});
```

I think at least in the current iteration of the SDK, [`include` only works with Arrays](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#relations-using-arrays) instead of Pointers.