# Not able to save a custom class object in Parse

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am trying to create a `Customer` class object which has a one to one relation with the `User` class. But the object doesn't save without giving any error.
Here is my code:

```
 Parse.Cloud.afterSave(Parse.User, function(request) {
 user = request.object;
 role_name = user.get("role_name");
 user_name = user.get("user_name");
 user_id = user.get("objectId");

  if (role_name == "customer"){
    user = request.object;
    console.log(" I am inside if else");

    var Customer = Parse.Object.extend("Customer");
    var cus = new Customer();
    cus.set("name2" , "albert")
    var relation = cus.relation("userId");
    relation.add(user);
    cus.save(); // Customer object should get saved here 

    cus.save(null, {
    success: function(cus) {
        // Execute any logic that should take place after the object is saved.
        console.log("I am working")
        alert('New object created with objectId: ' + cus.objectId);
    },
      error: function(error) {
        // handleParseError(error);
        console.log(error)
        // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
        // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
      }
    });
  }

});
```

Log when I run this:

```
  after_save triggered for _User for user qu808uKOgt:
  Input: {"object":{"createdAt":"2015-10-11T18:36:07.661Z","objectId":"qu808uKOgt","phone":"5678956475","role_name":"customer","updatedAt":"2015-10-11T18:36:07.661Z","username":"newuser16"}}
  Result: Success
  I am inside if else
  {"name2":"apple","userId":{"__op":"AddRelation","objects":      [{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"qu808uKOgt"}]}}
```

Comment: did you try to use 
`cus.save().then(function(saveObj){
   console.log("I am working")
},function(error){  console.log('error')  });`

Comment: @XenoN I tried but nothing happened

Comment: Not even error log ?

Comment: This is what I get -  `after_save triggered for _User for user qu808uKOgt:
  Input: {"object":{"createdAt":"2015-10-11T18:36:07.661Z","objectId":"qu808uKOgt","phone":"5678956475","role_name":"customer","updatedAt":"2015-10-11T18:36:07.661Z","username":"newuser16"}}
  Result: Success
I am inside if else
{"name2":"apple","userId":{"__op":"AddRelation","objects":[{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"qu808uKOgt"}]}}`

Comment: Edited question with the log please check

Comment: strange, btw did you really have to use relation between user and customer. I think in that case pointer could be good.
`cus.set("userId" , user)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91974/discussion-between-xenon-and-nik).

Comment: Quick thought. What is your used Javascript SDK version? If it is the latest one, you should change it back to version 1.4.2 (in your global.json) file as Parse currently has a bug in one of their JS SDK versions. Here is a thread where I described how to solve it exactly - http://stackoverflow.com/q/32667395/4988014

Comment: @EricSchanet Thank You so much. I fixed this thing by creating a new cloud function. Will try and see if I face this issue but for me the `customer` object wasn't getting saved. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this bug by creating a new cloud function, which will be called immediately after the user sign's up.

```
Parse.Cloud.define('functionName', function(request, response){
  var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
  var role_name =  currentUser.get("role_name");

  if (role_name == "customer"){
  // Do something
  }
  else if (role_name == "service_provider"){
  // Do something else 
  }
)};
```